# Advice for improving structural integrity of enclosed porch

Tags: roof, porch, ledger

I've recently purchased a home.  Home inspector said nothing about the back porch.  As I watch more youtube videos on framing and general home improvement, I look at my enclosed porch and think there may be some structural issues.  Would like input on how I can make this a little more solid and safe, as I don't want to tear it all down.  I've attached pictures.  Here are some things I've noticed.

1) Obviously, the ledger boards are attached over the siding, which is wrong.  I noticed there's not much holding the rafters in place on there other than nails.  Are there such things as rafter hangers (as opposed to flat joist hangers)?

2) Unless I'm missing something, shouldn't there be lag screws somewhere where it attaches to the house?

3) At the bottom of the roof, the notch on these rafters looks very big.  They appear attached to that 2x12 with nails, which is sitting on the notched (I assume) 4x4 posts (4 of them).  Are those ok?

[image: Ledger Board at House]
[image: Close up of Ledger Board and Rafters]
[image: Overall look at the bottom of the roof]
[image: Close up of 2x12 and rafter notches]

Comment: In order to review the structural integrity, we’ll need to know location, snow conditions, seismic activity, existing joist size and spacing, span of joists, overhang (if any), overall size of porch, size of notch at lower end, etc.

Comment: I think you have in part looked at two many videos. There are hangers but these do not work well for an angled application. You have 3 toe nail on each side that would work for me. The notch at the bottom may be large but what is the overhang? If it is just past the wall there is no problem. I would expect there to be lag bolts through the ledger into the structure the fact that there is a fair slope reduces many problems. How long has it been there? It may be fine but other than more than a little rebuilding to correct the issues you will be starting over, what type roof? Comp, metal?

Comment: @EdBeal How does, “a fair slope reduce many problems”?

Comment: With a good slope in snow country less weight will build up prior to sliding off. Normally the reason for a heavy notch on a porch like that is because the roof is close to flat add a notch doesn’t affect the roof as much as the overhang but adds more slope. A flat roof with almost no slope tends to leak more often and will end up carrying more weight.

Comment: why are there so many joists? each one doesn't have to hold very much like that...

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm just looking to see if any of these are red flags that need immediate attention or anything, namely the rafter connecting to the ledger or the depth of the notch at the end.  Was thinking of putting lag screws in the ledger, but just wondering if that's necessary.  I think the porch is about 14 feet long (from house to end of rafters) and width about 35 ish feet.  Rafters look to be 2x8, but I'd have to measure.  Spacing seems to be 16" OC.